# Get Max Entry_Sr_no from another table in SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have a SP, which gives me `mkey` and `doc_no` from one table.

Now I want to get the max of `entry_sr_no` of that respective `mkey` from the another table.

Here is my SP

```
alter procedure set_auto_action
    as 
        begin

            select mkey, doc_no from inward_doc_tracking_hdr 
           where status_flag not in (5,13)      
    end
```

I want to get `max` from `inward_doc_tracking_trl` table

The relation of both the table is something like below

`inward_doc_tracking_hdr` table `mkey` is equal to `inward_doc_tracking_trl` table `ref_mkey`

kindly suggest how to do this in SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join with `MAX()` should do it :

```
select hdr.mkey, hdr.doc_no,MAX(trl.entry_sr_no) as max_no
from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  hdr
JOIN inward_doc_tracking_trl trl
 ON(hdr.mkey = trl.ref_mkey)
where hdr.status_flag not in (5,13) 
GROUP BY hdr.mkey, hdr.doc_no
```

Comment: Well, that' simple and perfect. Even I tried the same thing but without `group by`, I was getting too many records...

Comment: Also, is this correct `and trl.U_Datetime < DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())` If I want to check the record is greater than one day in the same SP ?

Comment: Yes you can add conditions on the `WHERE` clause . @stack